# Twilio: Responding to a caller after transcript for previous response is received

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I'm trying to get the following flow to work:

1. Caller dials twilio #
2. We ask a question of the caller and they respond by speaking
3. Once the transcript is received (not the audio file), we respond by asking them another question... this goes on for 2-3 questions

**The problem I'm having is the separation of the calls to the main webhook handler, and the transcript handler.**

I have the primary call handler responding with the first question, as follows:

```
<!-- [/ handler] initial response, with the first question -->
<Response>
    <Say voice="alice">What is your favorite color? Press any key when done.</Say>
    <Record transcribe="true" transcribeCallback="/transcript" maxLength="60"/>
</Response>
```

Then we receive a second request to the primary call handler when the recording is completed. I can't respond with another question yet (business requirements), so we respond with a vague confirmation:

```
<!-- [/ handler] vague confirmation response
<Response>
    <Say voice="alice">Got it. Give me a couple seconds to write that down.</Say>
</Response>
```

Then I receive a hit on the `/transcript` handler with the transcript, to which I respond with:

```
<!-- [/transcript handler] Second question -->
<Response>
    <Say voice="alice">What is the air-speed velocity of an unladen swallow? Press any key when done.</Say>
    <Record transcribe="true" transcribeCallback="/transcription" maxLength="60"/>
</Response>
```

But apparently you can't respond to that handler with TWiML? The caller is hung up on after the second response from the `/` handler.

Any ideas on how I can implement this? I don't think I can really have the user wait in silence before responding to the second `/` handler request...

Comment: Is there any reason you are not using the TwiML Gather verb with Speech, https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather#input, to interact with the customer and just record the complete call?

Comment: The main thing is that this is interactive. I don't know how many times we go on this cycle until I've processed the transcript for each question. It might be a single question or it might be 6...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you receive a hit on your `/transcript handler` you have in the request the `callSid` (`CAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`) among other parameters.

With this `callSid` you can modify the *"in progress call"* my making a request to Twilio and passing a new TwiML.

Not sure what language are you using on your server side but in Node.js would look something like this:

```js
const accountSid = 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
const authToken = 'your_auth_token';
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.calls('CAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
      .update({twiml: '<Response>
    <Say voice="alice">What is the air-speed velocity of an unladen swallow? Press any key when done.</Say>
    <Record transcribe="true" transcribeCallback="/transcription" maxLength="60"/>
</Response>'})
      .then(call => console.log(call.to));
```

Docs: (https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-modify-calls-in-progress-node-js)

Comment: Thank you. That did it. I needed to add a pause after the "give me a few seconds" response just so it would keep the alive, but I was able to get it to read the next question.

But it's strange... After I respond to the second question, it immediately complains about an application error. The debugger shows that it's making a call out to some unknown host (`http://172.18.23.63:8520/v1/Accounts/[accountid]/Calls/[[callid]/twiml/[some other id]`), which is where the error is coming from... Any ideas what that is?

Comment: I think it's going in a loop. Maybe "Update a Call in progress with URL" fits better in this case (https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource?code-sample=code-update-a-call-in-progress-with-url&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=3.x).

Comment: You're welcome, glad it helped and good to know it solved a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

While you seem to have got this version of your call flow working, it is not the best way of approaching this issue as we now have [`<Gather input="speech">`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather).

`<Gather>` with the `input` set to "speech" will transcribe the user in real time, delivering the `SpeechResult` to your next webhook URL (the `action` attribute). This way you don't need to wait while the transcription is performed asynchronously and can respond with TwiML immediately.

Using `<Gather>` like this would let you build a call flow like:

```xml
<!-- [/ handler] initial response, with the first question -->
<Response>
  <Gather action="/question2" input="speech">
    <Say voice="alice">What is your favorite color?</Say>
  <Gather>
</Response>
```

Then in `/question2` you can dynamically read the response straight away. Here's how you could respond using Ruby and Sinatra as an example server side language:

```rb
post "/question2" do
  favorite_color = params["SpeechResult"]
  response = "Great, I love the color #{favorite_color} too. Now, what's your favorite pet?"
  return "<Response>
    <Gather action="/question3" input="speech">
      <Say>#{response}</Say>
    </Gather>
  </Response>"
end
```

And so on. You should find it a much better experience than using `<Record>` with transcription.

Comment: Thanks! Does Gather/Speech have a response time limit?

Comment: Sorry! Just. RTFM'd
> If you set input to speech, Twilio will gather speech from the caller for a maximum duration of 60 seconds.
This might work...